# JTextArea parameter and user input issues

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a JTextArea where I want to allow the user to input any number of strings up to 100 but it could be less. When I set the JTextArea as I have in my code below where it is commented out (i.e. //tfResult= new JTextArea(10, 0);) and the user inputs ten lines of strings then my code runs exactly as expected and prints out what I need it to.

But if I try to input more of less lines I get
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
followed by the number of lines of user input, whether I have it declared with no bounds or as I have it commented out.
I am new to graphics in java and I can't figure out why this is happening and I have searched everywhere for answers. Do I have the bounds set wrong or have I declared the JTextArea wrong?

I also am trying to include a JScrollPane but I am having issues with that also as its not showing up.

I would really appreciate any help as I am struggling to solve this issue.

```
class Window  {
    
    JFrame windowFrame;
    Panel bottomPanel;
    
    JScrollPane scroll;
    
    JTextArea tfResult;
    Button btnPlayAgain;
    Font font;

    
    Window(int width, int height, String title) 
    {
        windowFrame = new JFrame();
        
        windowFrame.setTitle(title);
        windowFrame.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
        windowFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        windowFrame.setResizable(true);
        windowFrame.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)); // setting cursor to hand
        windowFrame.setLayout(null);
      
        createBottomPanel();
        
        windowFrame.add(bottomPanel);
        //windowFrame.add(field.getCanvas());
        
        windowFrame.setVisible(true);        
    }    
   
    private void createBottomPanel()
    {
        JButton b = new JButton("Compute");
        
        bottomPanel = new Panel();
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        bottomPanel.setBounds(0,400,800,140);
        bottomPanel.setLayout(null);
        
        //*********
        //tfResult= new JTextArea(10, 0);
        tfResult= new JTextArea();
        
        tfResult.setBounds(10,10,600,100);
        tfResult.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        tfResult.setFocusable(true);
        
        scroll = new JScrollPane(tfResult);  
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
        
        btnPlayAgain = new Button("Compute");
        btnPlayAgain.setBounds(620,10,150,100);
        btnPlayAgain.setBackground(Color.RED);
        btnPlayAgain.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 24));
        btnPlayAgain.setFocusable(true);
        
        bottomPanel.add(tfResult);  
        bottomPanel.add(btnPlayAgain);  
        bottomPanel.add(b);
        bottomPanel.add(scroll);
         
        tfResult.setVisible(true);
        scroll.setVisible(true);
        btnPlayAgain.setVisible(true);
        bottomPanel.setVisible(true);
        
        btnPlayAgain.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            //@Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                
                //should include the code to genrate the output inside here 
                String input = tfResult.getText();
                Mat xy;
                xy = new Mat();
                
                //String output = xy.getOutput(input).toString();
                String output = xy.getOutput(input);
                
                //String output = Output(input);
                
                tfTarget.setText(output);
                
                
            }
            
        });
   
    }
}
```

Comment: For a JScrollPane to work, you have to add a JPanel to the JScrollPane.

Comment: @NomadMaker how do i do that

Comment: Just like you add any panel to another panel.

Comment: ***Never*** set the bounds of a JTextArea (or *any* Swing component, but especially the JTextArea), and in doing so, you prevent it from working as it is built to work or to work well inside of a JScrollPane. Please consider reading a few of the pertinent Swing tutorials.   You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: Regarding your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, you need to show the exception's stack trace with your question and indicate which line of *your code* throws it.

Comment: @NomadMaker: regarding *"For a JScrollPane to work, you have to add a JPanel to the JScrollPane. "* -- don't you mean that the OP needs to add the JScrollPane *to the displayed JPanel*? Looks like your suggestion is backwards.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use class [java.awt.Panel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Panel.html) and not class [javax.swing.JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) in this line of your code: `Panel bottomPanel;`? Are you sure that you want `java.awt.Button` (and not `javax.swing.JButton`) in this line of your code: `Button btnPlayAgain;`?

Comment: I see this is the fourth question you have asked on SO. Out of the other three questions, two were duplicates and one was closed. Have you read this? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @abra ive just made your alterations as i didnt realise there was a difference but when i do that my whole graphics frame is blank now

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for your help i was unaware of that!

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and created the following GUI that allows you to enter data with a `JTextArea`.

[image: JTextArea Inout GUI]

The first thing I did was start my Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Next, I created a `JFrame`.  Then I created a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`.  The `JTextArea` is inside of a `JScrollPane`, which is then placed inside of the center of a `JPanel`.

The `JButton` is placed after the last line of the `JPanel`.

Here's the complete runnable code, otherwise known as a minimal runnable example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JTextAreaInputGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JTextAreaInputGUI());
    }
    
    private JTextArea textArea;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextArea Input GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println(textArea.getText().trim());
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help i really appreciate it